# For a states dropdown, should you list CA provinces by default?

Tags: html, localization, internationalization

> This isn't exactly a programming
>   question, but it relates to web forms,
>   and the generation of markup for
>   states/provinces.

My site is by default the en-US locale and there is no Canadian version, should I list the Canadian provinces or should I just have a label that says something like "Other ( Province )" ?

I'm realizing that there are lots of provinces in every other country and it would be kinda unfair to list just Canada's by default.

In one of my previous questions a user said that he changes the states dropdown based on the country, so for example if a user selects "Canada" it would list the Canadian provinces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Canadian, and probably one of the most likely to order from a US site (outside the US), I really appreciate when Canadian provinces are listed. It seems fairly common these days and we only have 13 more items to add to a combo box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see any harm in doing this, and your Canadian users may very well appreciate being remembered. While you're there, Australia has Queensland, New South Wales, Victoria... :-)

If you're concerned about setting a precedent of showing states/provinces for other countries, just look at the usage stats and pick the top 5 countries or something.